# Fill color inside a shape on 3d plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have created a shape in matlab which look like this
[image: Shape image].

```
npts = 14;
z = linspace(-1,1,npts);
omz = sqrt(1-z.^2);

xyz=[2 3 1 0.5 2 5 10 15 20 29 32 34  10 2;1 3 8 12 20 25 27 25 23 26  26 23   5 1;z];
plot3(xyz(1,:),xyz(2,:),xyz(3,:),'ro','LineWidth',2);

box on
hold on
fnplt(cscvn(xyz(:,[1:end 1])),'r',2)
hold off
```

I need to fill different colors in this shape. How can I do this?

Comment: "different colors". How different? flat single colors or do you want more advanced stuff? Also, do you need to fill the curved function, or just the points? In other words, do you need that quadratic curvature filled or can one connect it with straight lines?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I want to feet the curve with shades of gray.  The shades will be decided by user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the output of `fnplt`.
2. change the colormap to `gray`.
3. use `fill3` to color the patch.

All together:

```
c = fnplt(cscvn(xyz(:,[1:end 1])),'r',2);
colormap gray
fill3(c(1,:),c(2,:),c(3,:),1:size(c,2))
```

the result:

[image: 3D_patch_color]

Comment: @swapnil gandhi, is this answers your question?

Comment: Partially, because user decides which color to put on which part of the shape?

Comment: @swapnilgandhi, I'll need an example here for the input from the user and the requested output on the shape.